# Access tabular form single cell referencing

Tags: ms-access, tabular

I have a tabular form derived from table

```
     A  B  C
 1  1A 1B 1C
 2
 3
```

What I need to do is changing back color of single cell after update, I can reference the field using me.[Field name] but then it change the backcolor of the whole column, is there any way I can do to specify color change to one cell like what I did using conditional formatting

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: Not in a form, but can be done in a report with Format and Print events. If CF accomplishes, why use VBA?

Comment: Thanks, but the form I am using is kind of interactive and user can choose different options, I dont know if it is proper way to display data. I use form to show data and user have to input ID to extract relevant data from few tables, seem I cant do this in report?